# Releasing memory after modal view dismiss

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, memory-management, modalviewcontroller

I am profiling an iOS application with Instruments, and I see that memory grows when I move around the UI of my app, but the memory nevers goes down. I double-checked and there are no memory leaks.

The problem seems to go worst when opening modal view controllers, I guess that its memory don't get released after dismiss them.

So my question is, is that a normal behaviour on iOS platform? Any clue on how to programatically release all alloc memory of a view once it's closed and it won't be displayed anymore?

Answer (score 0):

If you have `UIView` as **iVar** (class member variable) then release it in **dealloc** function.
If your view object is local then release it after you add it to superview.

```
MyView* myLocalView =   [[MyView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,width,height)];
[self.view addSubview:myLocalView];
[myLocalView release];
myLocalView = nil;
```

Comment: the problem is that on a modal view controller, the dealloc function never get called after dismiss it